# How to get load Data from server into RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I HAVE PROBLEM, WHY NOT ANY PEOPLE HELP ME?!**

In my application i want load data and use **lazy loader** for `recyclerView`.
**I write below code for load data :**

```
private void loadNews() {
    NewsSendData sendData = new NewsSendData();
    sendData.setKey("");

    newsPageImageProgress.show();

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<NewsResponse> call = api.getMainNews(sendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData().getNewsDatum() != null) {
                newModel.clear();
                newModel.addAll(response.body().getData().getNewsDatum());
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                newsPageRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    });
```

**And write below code in lazy loader for `recyclerView` :**

```
newsPageRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(layoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                    NewsSendData sendData = new NewsSendData();
                    sendData.setKey("");

                    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
                    Call<NewsResponse> call = api.getMainNews(sendData);

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
                            if (response.body().getData().getNewsDatum() != null) {
                                newsAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getData().getNewsDatum());
                                newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

I should use **searchView** in my application, and i want when users search text, **remove previous data** and just show new data from server (search result from server).
**For search result is use this code :**

```
newsSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {

                NewsSendData sendData = new NewsSendData();
                sendData.setKey(query);

                InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
                Call<NewsResponse> call = api.getMainNews(sendData);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<NewsResponse> call, Response<NewsResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body().getData().getNewsDatum() != null) {
                            newModel.clear();
                            newModel.addAll(response.body().getData().getNewsDatum());
                            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            newsPageRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
                            newsPageImageProgress.hide();

                            toolbarTitleTxt.setText(query);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<NewsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                });
```

I write above codes in **onCreate()** of activity.
When use above codes, show me data a lot of data from server.

**For example :** I when search text, show me 2 data in **PostMan**, but in my application show this 2 data top of datas and show other data below of this 2 data.

**When delete lazy loader code my issue is fix and just show this 2 datam but when add lazy loader again show me other datas!!!**

How can i fix this bug? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Replace your EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener code with the following one.

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener { 
public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName(); 
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount; 
private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load 
private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load. 
private int visibleThreshold = 4; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more. 
private int current_page = 1; 

private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager; 

public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager) { 
    this.mGridLayoutManager = gridLayoutManager; 
} 

@Override 
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) { 
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy); 

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount(); 
    totalItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getItemCount(); 
    int[] items = new int[3]; 
    mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(items); 
    firstVisibleItem = items[0]; 

    if (loading) { 
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) { 
            loading = false; 
            previousTotal = totalItemCount; 
        } 
    } 
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) { 
        // End has been reached 

        // Do something 
        current_page++; 

        onLoadMore(current_page); 

        loading = true; 
    } 
} 

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
```

}